# how to post <form> from jqxWindow

Tags: forms, post, jqxwidgets

I have modal jqxWindow

```
<div id='jqxwindow'>
    <div>Header</div>
    <div>Content   <div id='jqxMyCheckbox'>CheckBox</div>  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to post control values from this window by HTML  method.
If i add **Form** tags to the window, the jqxwindow seems to stop exists.
Please advice on right approach - how to Post control values from jqxwindow form.

please note, I'm looking for compact way, using declared controls only in HTML preferably. If i implement JQuery $.post method, I need to declare variables and control names again. That makes implementation too complex.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following post will be helpful to you

http://www.jqwidgets.com/submit-form-with-jqxlistbox/

In brief, try to assign 'name' property to some of jqWidgets you would like to include in post.